# how can I run cmd in windows 10 from cygwin emacs

Tags: windows, shell, emacs

I am running a cygwin shell under windows 10 in which I start a "screen" session and under that the cygwin version of emacs (24).  If I do M-xshell, it starts a cygwin (bash) shell just fine.  So for most of my programming I'm happy.  However, if within the cygwin shell I run "cmd" to get a "DOS prompt".  I get this weird error message from emacs, "Waiting for process to die" (and some more text about hitting ctrl-g).  I also get the same message, if I set the shell to be cmd by setting "explicit-shell-file-name" when I run shell.  (That's actually what I tried first.)

Now, if hit C-g (perhaps twice?), the shell appears and cmd appears to be running, but I'm not certain of the state of things.

Has anyone else seen this error message?  Googling for it returned nothing useful.  Is there some incompatibility between the cygwin build of emacs and running cmd?  Any hints on how to get around this problem?

Alternately, is there any way to send "builtin?" "DOS" commands (like MKLINK) under bash to a DOS box?  How about running .cmd files?  I really hate running a separate DOS box (not under emacs) and sometimes I need to do "DOS" things (and usually want the output captured in an emacs buffer).

Comment: I can't answer your main question, but you might take a look at using the `cygstart` bash command to run `.cmd` files.  Caveat: I have no personal experience using `cygstart` on anything other than directories.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron.  That was as close as I got to an answer.  cygstart didn't do what I want in this instance, but it does do things I need, so it was helpful in any case.